# What should I know about multithreading and when to use it, mainly in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I  have never come across multithreading but I hear about it everywhere.  What should I know about it and when should I use it?  I code mainly in c++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mostly, you will need to learn about MT libraries on OS on which your application needs to run. Until and unless C++0x becomes a reality (which is a long way as it looks now), there is no support from the language proper or the standard library for threads. I suggest you take a look at the POSIX standard pthreads library for *nix and Windows threads to get started.

Answer (score 2):

This is my opinion, but the biggest issue with multithreading is that it is difficult.  I don't mean that from an experienced programmer point of view, I mean it conceptually.  There really are a lot of difficult concurrency problems that appear once you dive into parallel programming.   This is well known, and there are many approaches taken to make concurrency easier for the application developer.  Functional languages have become a lot more popular because of their lack of side effects and idempotency.   Some vendors choose to hide the concurrency behind API's (like Apple's Core Animation).

Multitheaded programs can see some huge gains in performance (both in user perception and actual amount of work done), but you do have to spend time to understand the interactions that your code and data structures make.

Answer (score 2):

MSDN [Multithreading for Rookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810438.aspx) article is probably worth reading. Being from Microsoft, it's written in terms of what Microsoft OSes support(ed in 1993), but most of the basic ideas apply equally to other systems, with suitable renaming of functions and such.

Answer (score 2):

That is a *huge* subject.

A few points...

- With multi-core, the importance of multi-threading is now huge. If you aren't multithreading, you aren't getting the full performance capability of the machine.
- Multi-threading is *hard*. Communicating and synchronization between threads is tricky to get right. Problems are often intermittent, hard to diagnose, and if the design isn't right for multi-threading, hard to fix.
- Multi-threading is currently mostly non-portable and platform specific.

There are portable libraries with wrappers around threading APIs. Boost is one. wxWidgets (mainly a GUI library) is another. It *can* be done reasonably portably, but you won't have all the options you get from platform-specific APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to a good tutorial on **[POSIX threads programming](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)** (with diagrams) to get you started.  While this tutorial is pthread specific, many of the concepts transfer to other systems.

To understand more about when to use threads, it helps to have a basic understanding of parallel programming.  Here's a link to a tutorial on the very basics of **[parallel computing](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/parallel_comp/)** intended for those who are just becoming acquainted with the subject.

Answer (score 1):

I've got an [*introduction to multithreading*](http://www.stackframe.net/en/content/01-2009/introduction-multithreaded-programming) that you might find useful.

> In this article there isn't a single
>   line of code and it's not aimed at
>   teaching the intricacies of
>   multithreaded programming in any given
>   programming language but to give a
>   short introduction, focusing primarily
>   on how and especially why and when
>   multithreaded programming would be
>   useful.

Answer (score 0):

The other replies covered the *how* part, I'll briefly mention *when* to use multithreading.

The main alternative to multithreading is using a timer. Consider for example that you need to update a little label on your form with the existence of a file. If the file exists, you need to draw a special icon or something. Now if you use a timer with a low timeout, you can achieve basically the same thing, a function that polls if the file exists very frequently and updates your ui. No extra hassle.

But your function is doing a lot of unnecessary work, isn't it. The OS provides a "hey this file has been created" primitive that puts your thread to sleep until your file is ready. Obviously you can't use this from the ui thread or your entire application would freeze, so instead you spawn a new thread and set it to wait on the file creation event.

Now your application is using as little cpu as possible because of the fact that threads can wait on events (be it with mutexes or events). Say your file is ready however. You can't update your ui from different threads because all hell would break loose if 2 threads try to change the same bit of memory at the same time. In fact this is so bad that windows flat out rejects your attempts to do it at all.

So now you need either a synchronization mechanism of sorts to communicate with the ui one after the other (serially) so you don't step on eachother's toes, but you can't code the main thread part because the ui loop is hidden deep inside windows.

The other alternative is to use another way to communicate between threads. In this case, you might use `PostMessage` to post a message to the main ui loop that the file has been found and to do its job.

Now if your work can't be waited upon and can't be split nicely into little bits (for use in a short-timeout timer), all you have left is another thread and all the synchronization issues that arise from it.

It might be worth it. Or it might bite you in the ass after days and days, potentially weeks, of debugging the odd race condition you missed. It might pay off to spend a long time first to try to split it up into little bits for use with a timer. Even if you can't, the few cases where you can will outweigh the time cost.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that it's hard.  Some people think it's impossibly hard, that there's no practical way to verify that a program is thread safe.  Dr. Hipp, author of sqlite, states that [thread are evil.](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6)  This article covers the [problems with threads](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2006/EECS-2006-1.pdf) in detail.

The Chrome browser uses processes instead of threads, and tools like  [Stackless Python](http://www.stackless.com/) avoid hardware-supported threads in favor of interpreter-supported "micro-threads".  Even things like web servers, where you'd think threading would be a perfect fit, and moving towards event driven architectures.

I myself wouldn't say it's impossible: many people have tried and succeeded.  But there's no doubt writting production quality multi-threaded code is really hard.  Successful multi-threaded applications tend to use only a few, predetermined threads with just a few carefully analyzed points of communication.  For example a game with just two threads, physics and rendering, or a GUI app with a UI thread and background thread, and nothing else.  A program that's spawning and joining threads throughout the code base will certainly have many impossible-to-find intermittent bugs.

It's particularly hard in C++, for two reasons:

1. the current version of the standard d[oesn't mention threads at all](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq.html#threads).  All threading libraries and platform and implementation specific.
2. The scope of what's considered an atomic operation is rather narrow compared to a language like Java.

cross-platform libraries like [boost Threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/thread.html) mitigate this somewhat.  The future C++0x will introduce some threading support.  But boost also has good [interprocess communication](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) support you could use to avoid threads altogether.

If you know nothing else about threading than that it's hard and should be treated with respect, than you know more than 99% of programmers.

If after all that, you're still interested in starting down the long hard road towards being able to write a multi-threaded C++ program that won't segfault at random, then I recommend starting with [Boost threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/thread.html).  They're well documented, high level, and work cross platform.  The concepts (mutexes, locks, futures) are the same few key concepts present in all threading libraries.